# XML file error with Tectonicus 2.25

Tags: java, xml, macos, minecraft

I'm trying to make a Tectonicus map for my singleplayer world. Therefore I need a XML config file, but when trying to make the map I get this error in Terminal (MAC OSX):

```
"Parsing config from /Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
    at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.loadXml(Unknown Source)
    at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.parseConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't get root config node from /Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads
    at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.parseConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.main(Unknown Source)"
```

My file looks like this in Microsoft Word (OSX, 2016):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tectonicus version="2">
    <config mode="cmd" outputDir="/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads"/>
    <map name="GLACIER" worldDir="/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/GLACIER/level">
        <layer name="Day" lighting="day"/>
    </map>
</tectonicus>
```

What is the problem? Also I do not know if my xml is 1.0??? For answering, I'm not the best in XML programming, so please, keep the answer simple :)

EDIT: I've tried to locate a BOM, but there is no sign of it (Hex Friend, Emacs; still no sign). I do not know if there could be something else making the code 'false'.

EDIT: I remade the XML with Emacs, and checked for BOM's, which were not there.

Comment: check that the file is not encoded as [UTF with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: How? And what do I do when it is UTF with BOM, I'm using Xmplify now, and I don't see anything strange. Also XML validators on the internet say that there are no errors.

Comment: examine the file in a hex editor, remove the magic number or open in text editor and then save as "UTF without BOM"

Comment: Saving as UTF without BOM is not possible on texteditor on MAC OSX. When opening it with HEX FRIEND, should I delete all number on the left side?

Comment: how about googling for the answer?  http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/10/07/mac-os-x-removing-byte-order-mark-with-an-editor/

Comment: Strange, then there is no BOM.... Because there is no strange sign before <?xml etc....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you are using MS Word to make your XML (MS Word save the file in a incompatible format) ... Make the same XML but using Simple text editor like TextEdit ...

Comment: I made a new xml file using Emacs, that should be fine, right?

Comment: What happen is you add the `encoding` attribute to your xml declaration... try something like: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` ??

Comment: By the way, the exception says the file cannot be parsed; however, the exception also indicates that the code is trying to parse a path that points to a folder, not a file... where this path: `/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads`, is configured??